# Lubridate problems in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, lubridate, shiny-server

I have an issue with R shiny. I have written an R shiny application that does various things, one of the things it does is uses the Lubridate function below

```
df$UTCTime <- dmy_hms(df$UTCTime)

# note that this error cannot be fixed by using df[,2] instead of the "$" operator, as I have already tried this
```

This line of code works fine in base R, however in my R shiny application, it gives the output dates as a seemingly random sequence of numbers, like so

```
date <- dmy_hms(07/02/2019 22:03:21.714)  
# this gives the output date = 1549577001.71
```

I've recently introduced a function to my Shiny app and its caused a whole host of problems, that do not show up when you run the function in a normal R script, and I believe most of them can be traced back to this issue.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Here is a simplified version of my code, that produces the same error (there is no actual error, its just that all of the dates get converted to something like 1549577001.71).

```
library(shiny)
library(lubridate)

converter <- function(input_data){
    df <- input_data
    df$Date <- dmy_hms(df$Date)
    return(df)
}

ui <- fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(),
        mainPanel(
            tableOutput("contents")
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    output$contents <- renderTable({
        Date <- c("07/02/2019 22:03:21.714")
        df <- data.frame(Date)
        converter(df)
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I get ` dmy_hms("07/02/2019 22:03:21.714")#
[1] "2019-02-07 22:03:21 UTC"`

Comment: You should probably post the exact text of the error message.

Comment: There is no error message when doing this in R shiny, it simply just returns 1549577001.71. As I said, this does not happen in base R. I could post the R Shiny script if you think thats a good idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1549577001 is the internal representation of a `POSIXct` datetime object (number of seconds since 1970).
A solution is to output the date as `character`:

```
library(shiny)
library(lubridate)


converter <- function(input_data){
  df_ <- input_data
  df_$Date <- as.character(dmy_hms(df_$Date))
  return(df_)
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(),
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("contents")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$contents <- renderTable({
    Date <- c("07/02/2019 22:03:21.714")
    df <- data.frame(Date)
    converter(df)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]